# Noise simulation SPICE

Tags: noise, simulation, ltspice

My circuit is a capacitor multiplier. I want to generate some noise (200 mV) at 100 kHz and 500 kHz (input V) and want to see the attenuation on the output.

How can I generate specific frequency noise in SPICE/LTSPICE?

Comment: Since you want a single frequency it's easy - just use the sine wave signal generator. You need to define what you mean with a single frequency "noise".

Comment: I understood with the message above...simply use the sinewave signal generator and chose in the parameters the desired frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple voltage source as suggested. Or you can usa a voltage source and do an AC sweep over a frequency range. Here's a simple example:

[image: LP filter F0=159Hz]

This uses the AC analysis simulation. The voltage source is sweeps from 10Hz to 10kHz (1e4) using 50 steps pr octave. You can do the same thing with your circuit to get a nice bode plot of the transfer function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a voltage noise source and/or current noise source for use with LTspice you can download such noise sources on my GitHub page https://github.com/yildi1337/LTspiceNoiseSources.

Below you can find screenshots of two examples:

[image: Example with voltage noise source]
[image: Example with current noise source]